# Failed to determine database server error while attaching mdf file

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

While attaching .mdf file into Visual Studio 2013 i got following error.

[image]

My mdf file version is 2012..Visual Studio also use 2012 server.Now why this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I'm not sure there's anything you can do.  It sounds like the data file has corrupted when the drive failed.  If that is the case then I don't think there's any way you can get it running.

All I can think of is to send the error to *Paul Randal* (www.sqlskills.com) because if it's possible to recover it then he'll be able to and he's pretty quick at responding to requests.
However, you will get a lecture about not having backups and quite rightly.